# Why am i getting values out of the "between" range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a simple SQL query, and there's something that bothers me.

The syntax i'm using is:

```
select address_id, district, city_id from address

WHERE district = 'Alberta' OR district = 'QLD' OR district = 'Texas' OR district = 'Hamilton' 
OR district = 'California' OR district = 'Washington'

AND address_id BETWEEN 3 and 300;
```

This is what i'm getting. Notice that i get numbers that are lower than 3 and higher than 300 for address_id. Why is that? Am i missing something?

[image]

Also, is there any way to group the "district" options together instead of separating them with "or district =" multiple times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need parentheses . . . or `in`:

```
WHERE district IN ('Alberta', 'QLD', 'Texas', 'Hamilton', 'California' , 'Washington') AND
     address_id BETWEEN 3 and 300
```

If you don't fully understand how `AND` and `OR` are processed, then you should use parentheses.  You wrote:

```
WHERE district = 'Alberta' OR
      district = 'QLD' OR
      . . .
      (district = 'Washington' AND address_id BETWEEN 3 and 300)
```

Comment: Great! you answered both my questions, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

All those or statements are messing up, try to filter like this:

```
WHERE district IN ('Alberta', 'QLD', 'Texas', 'Hamilton', 'California' , 'Washington') AND
     address_id BETWEEN 3 and 300
```